# Disable кнопки в Хроме отменяет отправку формы

Tags: javascript

При отправки формы, хотелось бы отгородить пользователей от повторного нажатия пользователей на кнопку сабмит. Но хром при дизактивации кнопки, не отправляет форму. Как с этим бороться?

Comment: @Радик Камалов, не очень понятно, как происходит отправка формы. POST, GET? куда ведет action? В какой момент происходит "дезактивация" формы? Пожалуйста, напишите более развернутый вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Буквально 2 дня назад та же самая проблема была. Так вот сначала нужно отправлять форму, а затем только деактивировать кнопку.
Во как

```
<form ..... onsubmit="return this.submit.disabled='true';">
```